# Update a new field from table in a query

Tags: ms-access

In an access query, when I add a new field to one of the tables in the query, how can I get that new field to show up in the field list of that table within the query? I've been re-adding the table, resetting all of the various fields to point to that table_1 then removing the previous query...very annoying. Is there an easy way to "refresh" the table fields? Thanks!

Comment: Saving the table and reopening the query in design view should allow you to see the new field.  Or maybe saving the table and then pressing F5..... but definitely saving the table first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've been re-adding the table, resetting all of the various fields to point to that `table_1` then removing the previous query...

After modifying the referenced tables, closing & re-opening the Query should be sufficient to display the new fields:

[image: New Field]

Comment: @DataGrinder You're welcome - please mark my answer as the solution if it solved your issue, so that the question is shown as being resolved.